# Salesforce Hyperlink Formula Help

Tags: formula-field, hyperlink

I am looking for some help with a formula. I am trying to display a hyperlink to users based on the obj status and add another condition based on user profile. So far the formula works:

```
CASE (TEXT (Status),

"In Progress", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Complete", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Referred T", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Referred TM", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Referral Approved", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Referred U", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink Example","Edit Record", "_blank"),

"Unable to edit record"
)
```

However for the last value, I need to add a condition to only display based on profile id. This formula works on it's own:

```
IF (ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referred U") && $User.ProfileId = 'add id', HYPERLINK("hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"), "User unable to edit record"
)
```

How can I merge these together? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CASE (TEXT (Status),
    
    "In Progress", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),
    
    "Complete", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),
    
    "Referred T", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),
    
    "Referred TM", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),
    
    "Referral Approved", HYPERLINK("Hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"),
    
    "Referred U", IF (ISPICKVAL( Status , "Referred U") && $User.ProfileId = 'add id', HYPERLINK("hyperlink example","Edit Record", "_blank"), "User unable to edit record"),
    
    "Unable to edit record"
    )
```

Comment: better: `$Profile.Name` (at least for mono-language orgs)